# which of the following is necessarily true for a function $f : X \rightarrow Y$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

which of the following is  necessarily true  for  a  function$ f : X \rightarrow Y $?

1) if $ f$ is injective ,then there exists  $g : Y \rightarrow X$ such that  $f(g(y) =y$  for  all  $y \in Y.$

2) if  f is surjective ,then there exists  $g : Y \rightarrow X $such that  $f(g(y) =y$  for  all  $y \in Y.$

3) if  $f$ is injective  and $Y $ is countable then X  is finite.

4) if $ f$ is surjective  and $X$ is  uncountable then  $Y$ is  countably 
infinite

My attempts : option 3   is  wrong take $ f$ :N$ $ $\rightarrow$ N

option $4$ is  wrong take  $f : R \rightarrow R$

option $1$ is true   and option $2$  is also Trues   as both are  True because  take $f(x) = x$

Is  my answer  is correct or not  pliz verified its....

thanks

Comment: 1 and 2 are not both true. You can show something is false by counterexample, but you can't show something is true by example.

Comment: 2 depends on the axiom of choice ... But more importantly, something that is true for one specific $f$ is not *necessarily* true for *every* $f$.

Comment: You haven't actually provided counterexamples for 3 or 4.

Comment: that  was  my only logics @Bungo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f is surjective ,then there exists  $g : Y \rightarrow X $such that  $f(g(y) =I$  for  all  $y \in Y.$

take  X ={1}  and$ Y$ ={$1,2$},   as  for option  $1)$  $ f$  is injective  that mean $f(1) = 1$  but  f is not onto  so it is false

so  option $2 $ is true

Answer (score 1):

1) If $ f $ is  injective it means that you can get the input back given the output, which means the existence of $ g $ giving or the identity by composing the other way around.

Note that this is not a proof that what you wrote is wrong,  but it shows you the correct version.

2) $ f $ being surjective means that for every possible output $ y $ you can *choose* (axiom of Choice as mentioned in the comments) a preimage and call it $ g (y) $. Then indeed $ f (g (y))=y$ by construction.